# Match date by year

Tags: mysql, date, yii2

I have a date column in a table where I stored the date in Y-m-d format. I want to make a find() where the year of that date is, for example, 2016. LIKE it doesn't work for dates. 
I found that in pure mysql I can do

```
select * from your_table where year(date) = 2016
```

But how can I do this on Yii2? Is there a native way or I need to make a custom query?

P.S. Im working on Yii2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use active record :

```
TableName::find()->where(['YEAR(date)' => 2016])->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select * from your_table where YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date_column, "%Y-%m-%d")) = 2016
```

Or

```
 select * from your_table where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_column) = 2016
```

Comment: I can do it on mysql with the query I posted. Im looking for a Yii2 option.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by it is not working for Yii2. It's `php` framework right ? Ultimately, your query is going to execute on `mysql` . right ?

Answer (score 0):

try this,,

```
//Using model/Active Record
TableName::find()->where('year(date_column) =:date_column' , [':date_column' => '2016'])->all();

//Using Active Query
Yii::$app->db->createCommand('select * from table_name where year(date_column) = 2016')->queryAll();
```

For more example, you can read this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap 'YEAR(date)' in where condition like this:

TableName::find()->where([new yii\db\Expression('YEAR(date)') => 2016])->all();

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html#$expression-detail